# Asterisk - how to execute script on call received

Tags: asterisk

How can I execute a script to open our CRM app on the specific client CALLERID in when the call is answered in asterisk (on the computer of the receiver of the call and not the server asterisk) ?
I can execute a script on the server, but can't do it on the client that reveives the call.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need asterisk events

https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+11+AMI+Events

Event can be AgentConnect if you use queues or Join/Bridge if you need it fire without queues.

You need write always-running daemon which will fire your scripts on event.